# Still confusing the rules around selecting columns, group by, and joins

Tags: sql, group-by, syntax

I am still confused by the syntax rules of using `GROUP BY`. I understand we use `GROUP BY` when there is some aggregate function. If I have even one aggregate function in a SQL statement, do I need to put all of my selected columns into my `GROUP BY` statement? I don't have a specific query to ask about but when I try to do joins, I get errors. In particular, when I use a count(*) in a statement and/or a join, I just seem to mess it up.

I use BigQuery at my job. I am regularly floored by strange gaps in knowledge.

Thank you!

Comment: Obviously, syntax can vary slightly between different RDBMS, but - as a general rule - any columns that are part of your SELECT statement, but are not aggregated, will need to be included in the GROUP BY.  If you then start incorporating table joins, then there may be a little more complexity to it, depending on your expected results.  You say you don't have a specific query, but you also say that you get errors - so you must have queries that you are running, that are producing the errors.  It probably would be best to include an example query, then you can get some more specific advice

Comment: Thank you! I will update with a query when I run across it again. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a little complicated.

First, no aggregation functions are needed in an aggregation query.  So this is allowed:

```
select a
from t
group by a;
```

This is equivalent, by the way, to:

```
select distinct a
from t;
```

If there are aggregation functions, then no `group by` is needed.  So, this is allowed:

```
select max(a)
from t;
```

Such an aggregation query -- with no `group by` -- *always* returns one row.  This is true even if the table is empty or a `where` clause filters out all the rows.  In that case, most aggregation functions return `NULL`, with the notable exception of `count()` that returns `0`.

Next, if you mix aggregation functions and non-aggregation expressions in the `select`, then in general you want the non-aggregation, non-constant expressions in the `group by`.  I should note that you *can* do:

```
select a, concat(a, 'bcd'), count(*)
from t
group by a;
```

This should work, but sometimes BigQuery gets confused and will want the expression in the `group by`.

Finally, the SQL standard supports a query like this:

```
select t.*, count(*)
from t join
     u
     using (foo)
group by t.a;
```

When `a` is the primary key (or equivalent) in `t`.  However, BigQuery does not have primary keys, so this is not relevant to that database.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate this.

Comment: Is the "t.*" a way to pull in all the records of a given table? I am not familiar with that construction. Thank you!

Comment: @lillemongrab . . . `t.*` is a way to pull in all the *columns* that `t` refers to.